# A number in the mirror algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm which can show me the number I enter in the mirror. I mean, if I enter 173, it should show me that the number in the mirror is 371. I wrote the code, but something it's not working and I can't figure what. Thanks a lot !

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Citire(int &n)
{
    cout  << "\nda numarul:";
    cin   >> n;
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "ai gresit, da natural:";
        cin >> n;
    }
}

int Oglinda(int &n)
{
    int Og = 0;
    int UltCif;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        UltCif = n % 10;
        Og = Og * 10 + UltCif;
        n = n / 10;


    }
    return Og;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int Og;

    Citire(n);
    Oglinda(Og);

    cout << endl << Og << " este oglinda numarului " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: You're using `Og` uninitialized. How is that supposed to work? It's plain old undefined behavior.

Comment: If I run it, Og is something like 1321321312, I mean random.

Comment: @user3348368 yes, because it's uninitialized.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Forgot about that. But why is n 0 all the time now?

Comment: @user3348368 because it's passed by reference and you are dividing it by 10 until it's zero. Pass it by value instead. And learn the basics of C++, for the love of it! You're wasting your time and ours as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
Og = Oglinda(n);
```

And that function's signature should be:

```
int Oglinda(int n);
```

Otherwise, you're modifying `n` in the function - which you don't want to do since you want to print its original value at the end.

Comment: @user3348368 because you're reducing it to zero in your function. Change it to take it by-value instead of by-ref.

Comment: Working like charm. Thanks a lot !:)